# Return values from modal dialog in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to override the window.confirm in ExtJS 4. The override should return either true or false (just like confirm but with great UI).

```
window.confirm=function(msg) {var val=Ext.create("Ext.Window",{
    title : 'Extra window!',
    width : 150,                            
    height: 100,
    closable : true,                           
    html : msg,                         
    modal : true,
    onEsc:aa,
    items:[
           {
               xtype:'button',
               text:'Ok',
               handler:function()
               {
                   return true;
               }
           },
           {
               xtype:'button',
               text:'Cancel',
               handler:function(){
                   return false;
               }
           }
           ]
}).show();
function aa(btn)
{
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting the modal window wherever I use confirm, but it's not returning either true or false, its running asynchronously.

I tried with showModalDialog instead of confirm, this time too I'm not getting return value.

Is it possible to return true or false based on user selection (when user selects ok then return true, false when clicking cancel)

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: confirm returns me true or false based on user selection, i want similar functionality with enhanced UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call modal dialog in a sync fashion. If you want to wrap it somehow into utility function that you will call from different places in your application you need to do something like this:

```
showConfirmationDialog: function(question, yesCallback) {
    //... Create you window
    //... Show window - add handler to the YES button and call yesCallback from it
},

...

otherFunction: function() {

   this.showConfirmationDialog('Do you want to delete record?', function() {
      // Delete record
   });

}
```

Comment: so, doing a replica of confirm ( styled ) is impossible ?

Comment: No. it's still gonna be event driven and async.

Comment: Instead of confirm, can we implement with showModalDialog(), as mentioned in the following link,https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/showModalDialog.html

Comment: Again - you would need to pass a handler function to the modal dialog. I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: I was very desperate to implement such an alternate, as of now i'm not done. Anyway,thanks for your comments

Comment: It is a very common task actually. But if you are going to work with JS you need to adapt to the paradigm of async execution.